# How to load a model with tf.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, conv-neural-network

import tensorflow as tf  Tensorflow 2.0

i saw that i can load a model from tensorflow like this

```
    image_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
```

Now i want to be able to load models from local machine. My issue is that i can not find an pretrained model that works like this:

```
    image_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('inception_v4.h5')  (i used h5  from here https://github.com/titu1994/Inception-v4/releases?fbclid=IwAR0pK_CZaB9RwA92nvawNOha6DjY5xI0vtkc9Ff5HTATcFT9x5vGYBUXt5Q  (first h5 model))

       future: <Task finished coro=<server_task.<locals>.server_work() done, 
    defined at ....\x.py:249> exception=ValueError('No model found in config file.')>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "....\x.py", line 280, in server_work
        image_model, layers_indices = init(model_choice, layers_to_see)
      File "....\x.py", line 146, in init
        image_model = options[choice]() 
    #tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', 
    pooling='avg')
      File "....\x.py", line 119, in model_H5_model
        image_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('..../inception_v4.h5')
      File "...\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 146, in 
    load_model
        return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
      File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
   packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 165, in load_model_from_hdf5
     raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
    ValueError: No model found in config file.
```

I also tried with a model like this

```
    image_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.pb') 
  File "....\x.py", line 280, in server_work
    image_model, layers_indices = init(model_choice, layers_to_see)
  File "....\x.py", line 146, in init
    image_model = options[choice]() 
   #tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', 
   pooling='avg')
     File "....\x.py", line 119, in model_H5_model
    image_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('.../model/inceptionv4.pb')
     File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
     packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 149, in 
     load_model
     loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
       File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
      packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 83, in 
      parse_saved_model    
      constants.SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME_PB))
      OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: 
       .../model/inceptionv4.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

What i also tried was smth like this:

```
    image_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(include_top=True, 
    weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
    image_model.save('test') - >  when trying to save i receive this error

    File "\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 905, in 
    wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    TypeError: in converted code:
       relative to ...\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages:

    tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py:606 initialize_variables  *
        for v, init in initializer_map.items():
    tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py:438 converted_call
        if not options.user_requested and 
    conversion.is_whitelisted_for_graph(f):
        m = tf_inspect.getmodule(o)
    tensorflow_core\python\util\tf_inspect.py:337 getmodule
        return _inspect.getmodule(object)
    pycallgraph\tracer.py:372 wrapper
        if rest not in cache:

    TypeError: unhashable type: 'ObjectIdentityDictionary'

    tf.keras.models.load_model('test_model')
```

I am wondering where i can find a h5 file or pb (pretrained model) that actually works with tf.keras.models.load_model()

Based on the first comment :

```
future: <Task finished coro=<server_task.<locals>.server_work() done, defined at c:\Users\...\Desktop\PrivateStuff\...\...\xx.py:249> exception=TypeError("in converted code:\n    relative to C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages:\n\n    tensorflow_core\\python\\eager\\def_function.py:606 initialize_variables  *\n        for v, init in initializer_map.items():\n    tensorflow_core\\python\\autograph\\impl\\api.py:438 converted_call\n        if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_whitelisted_for_graph(f):\n    tensorflow_core\\python\\autograph\\impl\\conversion.py:352 is_whitelisted_for_graph\n        m = tf_inspect.getmodule(o)\n    tensorflow_core\\python\\util\\tf_inspect.py:337 getmodule\n        return _inspect.getmodule(object)\n    pycallgraph\\tracer.py:372 wrapper\n        if rest not in cache:\n\n    TypeError: unhashable type: 'ObjectIdentityDictionary'\n")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Desktop\PrivateStuff\...\...\xx.py", line 280, in server_work
    image_model, layers_indices = init(model_choice, layers_to_see)
  File "c:\Users\...\Desktop\PrivateStuff\...\...\xx.py", line 146, in init
    image_model = options[choice]() #tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
  File "c:\Users\...\Desktop\PrivateStuff\...\...\xx.py", line 55, in model_VGG16
    image_model.save(r'c:\test')
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 975, in save
    signatures, options)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 115, in save_model
    signatures, options)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\save.py", line 74, in save
    save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\save.py", line 870, in save
    checkpoint_graph_view)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\signature_serialization.py", line 64, in find_function_to_export
    functions = saveable_view.list_functions(saveable_view.root)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\saved_model\save.py", line 141, in list_functions
    self._serialization_cache)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 2422, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    .list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\base_serialization.py", line 91, in list_functions_for_serialization
    fns = self.functions_to_serialize(serialization_cache)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\layer_serialization.py", line 79, in 
functions_to_serialize
    serialization_cache).functions_to_serialize)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\layer_serialization.py", line 94, in 
_get_serialized_attributes
    serialization_cache)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\model_serialization.py", line 47, in 
_get_serialized_attributes_internal
    default_signature = save_impl.default_save_signature(self.obj)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\saving\saved_model\save_impl.py", line 206, in default_save_signature
    fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 777, in get_concrete_function    
    self._initialize_uninitialized_variables(initializer_map)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 616, in _initialize_uninitialized_variables
    return initialize_variables.get_concrete_function()()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1891, in get_concrete_function       
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2150, in _maybe_define_function      
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2041, in _create_graph_function      
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 905, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in converted code:
    relative to C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages:

    tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py:606 initialize_variables  *
        for v, init in initializer_map.items():
    tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py:438 converted_call
        if not options.user_requested and conversion.is_whitelisted_for_graph(f):
    tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\conversion.py:352 is_whitelisted_for_graph
        m = tf_inspect.getmodule(o)
    tensorflow_core\python\util\tf_inspect.py:337 getmodule
        return _inspect.getmodule(object)
    pycallgraph\tracer.py:372 wrapper
        if rest not in cache:

    TypeError: unhashable type: 'ObjectIdentityDictionary'
```

Comment: I don't get the question, what happens when you load those models, do you get errors? If so, add them to your question. You need to tell us what is actually going wrong.

Comment: the files on the Github page you reference are weights files not the full model file.

Comment: Can you give me an example of usable full model file ?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code to load MobileNet. It works if your provide a full path to save the model. See code below. Note when you load a model with weights='imagenet' the weights are set for the model trained on the imagenet data set. You don't need to load any weights. Now if you want to load weights for the model pre-trained on some other data set first instantiate the model as shown below. Then load the specific weights using model.load_weights.

```
image_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(include_top=True, 
    weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
image_model.save(r'c:\test')
```

Comment: And if for example i want to use the same model to be loaded i  just use tf.keras.models.load_model('c:\test') ?

Comment: I tried like you said but  it did not work, i added the error aswell